# Which manner of processing two repetative operations will be completed faster?

Tags: java, performance, for-loop

Generally speaking, is there a significant differance in the processing speeds of these two example segments of code, and if so, which should complete faster? Assume that "processA(int)" and "processB(int)" are voids that are common to both examples.

```
for(int x=0;x<1000;x++){
    processA(x);
    processB(x);
}
```

or

```
for(int x=0;x<1000;x++){
    processA(x);
}
for(int x=0;x<1000;x++){
    processB(x);
}
```

I'm looking to see if I can speed up one of my programs and it involves cycling through blocks of data several times and processing it differant ways. Currantly, it runs a seperate cycle for each processing method, meaning a lot of cycles get run in total, but each cycle does very little work. I was thinking about rewriting my code so that each cycle incorporates every processing method; in other words, much fewer cycles, but each cycle has a heavier workload.

This would be a very intensive rewrite of my program stucture. So unless it would give me a significant performance boost, it won't be worth the trouble.

Comment: Fairly certain that the first (single cycle that runs both) would be faster (assuming that A,B are independent and the code is consecutive without things that we are missing in between).

This is simply by counting actions because in a single loop you save 1000 calls to ++.
Other then that, I am not aware of any difference.

Comment: You also save 1000 comparisons of x to 1000.

Comment: @BrettOkken @Elayeek I'm pretty sure the 1000 comparisons of x (and the 1000 calls to ++) are ironed out by the compiler/JVM (especially since `1000` is hardcoded) so the improvement of the first example over the second is insignificant at best.

Comment: @Ceiling Gecko I was simply pointing out that while Elayeek only mentions calls to ++x, there are also comparisons of x to 1000. I agree that there is likely little difference in performance, especially if executed enough to be optimized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first case will be slightly faster then the second case because a for loop in and of itself has an effect on performance. However, the main question you should ask yourself is this: will the effect be of significance to my program? If not, you should opt for clear and readable code.

One thing to remember in such a case is that the JVM (Java Virtual Machine) does a whole lot of optimisation, and in your case the JVM can even get rid of the for-loop and rewrite the code into 1000 successive calls to processA() and processB(). So even if you have two for loops, the JVM can get rid of both, making your program more optimal than even your first case.

To get a basic understanding of method calls, cost, and the JVM, you can read this short article:

https://plumbr.eu/blog/how-expensive-is-a-method-call-in-java

Answer (score 2):

The single loop case will contain fewer instructions so will run faster.

But, unless `processA` and `processB` are very quick functions, such a substantial refactoring would give you negligible performance gain.

If this is production code, you should also take care as there may be side effects. You should make alterations in the context of a unit testing framework testing the code in question. (In C++ for example `x` may be passed by reference and could be modified by the functions! Of course Java has no such hazard but there may be other reasons why all `processA` functions have to run before all `processB` functions and the program comments may not make this clear).

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, fusing the 2 loops will be faster. (Some compilers do this automatically as an optimization.) How much faster? That depends on how many iterations the loops are running. Unless the number of iterations is **very** high, you can expect that the improvement will be minimal.

Answer (score 1):

The first piece of code is faster, because it only has one for loop.

If, however, you need to do something AFTER processA() has been executed n times and before processB()'s loop starts, then the second option would be ideal.